# Error assets/.env 403 (Forbidden) - Futter web

Tags: flutter

My website that is in production was working correctly and today the following error appeared when entering the link on my website, this mentioned error prevents me from viewing my website, can you tell me what I can do to solve it please, thank you.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the file's permissions, is it readable?